# Не видит подключенный в main.js vue-resource

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Я подключил в main.js vue-resource

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import './plugins/vuetify'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import vueResource from "vue-resource"

Vue.use(vueResource);

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  components: {App},
    render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

Затем использую его в модуле store user.js
файл store/index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import user from './modules/user'
import common from './modules/common'

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
        common,
        user
    }
})
```

В компоненте
файл store/modules/user.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
// import vueResource from "vue-resource";
//
// Vue.use(vueResource);
//
let userRequest = Vue.resource('/user{/id}')
```

Код работает только если раскомментировать код выше

Ошибка

> user.js?0f9a:7 Uncaught TypeError:
>   vue__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.default.resource is not a function

let userRequest = Vue.resource('/user{/id}') - место ошибки

Comment: в файле main.js попробуйте поменять местами строчки с подключением store и vue-resource

Comment: по прежнему не работает. Если это поможет from от store в webstorm выделен отличным от других from цветом, но сообщений никаких нет

Comment: а, я немного не правильно сказал - store подключите ниже Vue.use(vueResource);

Comment: Ничего не изменилось

Comment: Лучше использовать axios, https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/using-axios-to-consume-apis.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выдержка из [документации](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html#%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2):

> Некоторые официальные плагины Vue.js, такие как `vue-router`, автоматически вызывают `Vue.use()`, если обнаружат глобальную переменную `Vue`. Однако при использовании инструментов модульного окружения, например CommonJS, необходимо всегда вызывать `Vue.use()` явно:

```
// При использовании CommonJS посредством Browserify или Webpack
var Vue = require('vue')
var VueRouter = require('vue-router')

// Не забудьте этот вызов!
Vue.use(VueRouter)
```

**Конец цитаты.**

Под глобальной переменной подразумевается подключение `vuejs` следующим образом:

```
window.Vue = require('vue');
```

Таким образом, в вашем случае необходимо писать `Vue.use(...)`:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'

Vue.use(VueResource)
```